# how to call another function after complete colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Can I run another function after complete colorbox

```
function _teamPopup(){
    $(".members-group").colorbox({
        inline:true, 
        rel:'members-group',
        href:$(this).attr('href'),
        scrolling: false,
        onComplete:function() {
            //runMyFunction pass href value also
          }     
    });
}
```

How to run below function after complete colorbox and I need to pass some values to my function. Can I do this:

```
function myFunction(hrefvalue){
    alert(hrefvalue);
}
```

Comment: seriously??? onComplete:function() { //runMyFunction pass href value also } <------ it's there already

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need to do it, the callback is actually named `onComplete`, pretty much straightforwad, anyhow, you can do it as follows:

```
function _teamPopup(){
    $(".members-group").colorbox({
        inline:true, 
        rel:'members-group',
        href:$(this).attr('href'),
        scrolling: false,
        onComplete:function() {
            myFunction($(this).attr('href'));
        }.bind(this)//Bound to be able to get the href.    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call it:

```
onComplete: function() {
  myFunction($(this).attr('href'));
}
```